Trace memory allocated by cl.exe while running build on windows
I am trying to compiler .c files on windows OS with micros VC. Some times builds are intermittently failing with fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space. So during build time i want to understand how much memory is being allocated by the compiler (cl.exe). So that i can have full proof to gather the information like in what scenarios build is failing...etc i want to trace that details in build log to further debug it.
Do we have any tools or flags that helps here for memory traceability?

How big and complex is the project? It might be worth trying it with the Intel ICX compiler to see if that can handle it any better. Otherwise you have to try and get a reproducible failure - intermittent failures are almost impossible to debug. I have seen the odd one where failures during compilation of buggy code can sometimes trap/lock resources so that after a while something has to give. Watching it from task manager might shed some light on what is going on and when it starts to go haywire.

I am dealing with huge project with 100's of .c files to compiler. I cant switch the compiler. I need some way around to reproduce the issue and fix the problem. Intermittent issues are hard to reproduce. May be i forcefully increase the memory followed by running the build to see if i can reproduce the issue. But for that also , how can we forcefully increase the memory on windows machine ?

Best thing I can suggest is keep a log of when it fails and what you were doing/which file was compiling at the time in the hope of narrowing it down. Your question appears to be a duplicate of MSVC Compiler out of heap space and the relevant incantation is allegedly /Zm and to look for certain syntax errors. I can't say I have ever encountered it myself. A clean build from scratch on a newly rebooted machine might be one way to control random variables. Good luck!
